# How to make a function call only once in Swift 3.1?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a class that looks a little like:

```
final class Token {

..........

public enum Result {

    case Success()
    case Failure(Error)

}

private var successClosure : (() -> Void)?
private var failureClosure : ((Error) -> Void)?

public func completed(withResult result: Token.Result) {

    switch result {
       case .Success: successClosure?()
       case .Failure(let error): failureClosure?(error)
    }

}

..........

}
```

I would like to enforce the ability to call `completed(withResult:)` only once.

Is there a method of converting the above `completed(withResult:)` method to one that is compatible with Swift 3.1?

Comment: What is the scope of this "once"? Once for the lifetime of the app being installed? Once per execution of the app? Once per lifetime of the class instance? Something else?

Comment: Every scenario can be solved with a simple boolean test.

Comment: Once for the lifetime of the class instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a boolean variable which changes to `false` when the function was called once.

```
fileprivate var firstCompletionTime = true

public func completed(withResult result: Token.Result) {
    guard firstCompletionTime else {
        return
    }

    switch result {
       case .Success: successClosure?()
       case .Failure(let error): failureClosure?(error)
    }

    firstCompletionTime = false
}
```

Comment: You'll want to use a semaphore instead. This will easily break in a multithreaded context, which this call-back based code is probably using.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand the requirement well enough to write a sample code that exactly addresses your needs, but generally speaking, you might consider using `dispatch_once` as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1447169-dispatch_once).

Comment: dispatch_once is not available in Swift 3.

Comment: The use of `dispatch_once` (or its Swift 3 equivalent) is only useful for certain definitions of "once" in the OP's question. I wouldn't recommend it until the OP clarifies their question.